# Searching two multidimensional arrays for the same value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to figure how to create a function that returns a value in a multidimensional array based on its key, while looping though another multidimensional array.

Example: Sample JSON API response that's been converted to an array:

Products array

```
[225]=>
  array(10) {
    ["id"]=> int(1571)
    ["product"]=> string(11) "shirts"
    ["group"]=> array(1) {
      [0]=> int(1146)
    }
  }
 [226]=>
  array(11) {
    ["id"]=>  int(1572)
    ["product"]=> string(11) "shoes"
    ["group"]=> array(1) {
      [0]=> int(1147)
    }
  }
```

Using a foreach loop, get product name (e.g. shirts) and pass it to a function which returns the sales figure for that product.  This value is in another array (Sales) that looks like this:

```
'shirts' => 
  array (
    'date' => '2021-05',
    'sales' => 100,
  ),
  'shoes' => 
  array (
    'date' => '2021-05',
    'sales' => 4000,
  ),
```

My first thought was to use array_search of an array_column, but the value I'm looking to match is a key.  So now I think I need to have a loop within my function which returns the array keys and values of the Sales array, finds a key match based on the value I passed in, and then find the corresponding sales number. It's not working as expected though and I'm wondering if there is an easier way of doing this. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Can we see your code?

Comment: Why would this be difficult, you loop through the Products Array, pick out the `product` name and use that as the key into the Sales array. Simples

Comment: Apologies.  My code was working, but I didn't realize that I wasn't getting the full API response.  All good now.